# Reference field of users in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, users

I am using [Toolset](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) for custom post type 
and want to create field reference for users inside a custom post
is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use users as reference in your custom post types by checked  **Author** checkbox under **Sections to display when editing** displayed in attached image.

[image]

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: but Author will grep all users, and i want to display user of custom "role"
and the "role" has no privileges to write or edit content, its just registered user.